# Get users with same IP Address between 300 seconds from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data like this

```
IP Address    | UserName | DateTime            |
198.168.1.101 | User 1   | 2019-01-01 9:00:00  |
198.168.1.101 | User 2   | 2019-01-01 9:00:05  |
198.168.1.101 | User 3   | 2019-01-01 9:00:10  |
198.168.1.101 | User 4   | 2019-01-01 9:00:15  |
198.168.1.101 | User 5   | 2019-01-01 10:00:00 |
```

From this record,  **User 1 until 4** was login less than 300 seconds. So I need to capture this data and notify to system admin.

I no idea how to query on the SQL. Criteria is

1. Same IP Address
2. Within 300 second

With this script, I will get all that user

```sql
SELECT UA.*
FROM UserAccess UA join
     (SELECT IPAddress
      FROM UserAccess
      GROUP BY IPAddress
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) GUA
     on UA.IPAddress = GUA.IPAddress;
```

How can I made it?

Comment: Do you mean that you need all the users within first 300 seconds?

Comment: Can you span your sample data please? I don't see your criteria. What do you take as minuend, every four users? Thanks

Comment: So, you have 3 accesses from the same IP address spaced 290 seconds apart. This means the gap between the first and the last access is, in total, 580 seconds. Do all 3 of these accesses form a single group? If so, are there any limitations on how big this temporal grouping can become? If not, which one(s) aren't in the group and why?

Answer (score 0):

use self join

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88a007e9c4f08ba533b061a4689b42fd)**

```
select distinct A.* FROM t1 a join t1 b 
on a.ipaddress=b.ipaddress and b.datetimeval>a.datetimeval
```

OUTPUT:

```
ipaddress       username    datetimeval
198.168.1.101   User 1     01/01/2019 09:00:00
198.168.1.101   User 2     01/01/2019 09:00:05
198.168.1.101   User 3     01/01/2019 09:00:10
198.168.1.101   User 4     01/01/2019 09:00:15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @UserAccess TABLE (IPAddress VARCHAR(16), UserName VARCHAR(20), [DateTime] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @UserAccess VALUES
('198.168.1.101', 'User 1', '2019-01-01 9:00:00'),
('198.168.1.101', 'User 2', '2019-01-01 9:00:05'),
('198.168.1.101', 'User 3', '2019-01-01 9:00:10'),
('198.168.1.101', 'User 4', '2019-01-01 9:00:15'),
('198.168.1.101', 'User 5', '2019-01-01 10:00:00')

SELECT IPAddress, UserName, [DateTime] FROM @UserAccess U1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM @UserAccess U2 WHERE 
                    U1.IPAddress = U2.IPAddress 
                    AND  ( U2.[DateTime] BETWEEN DATEADD(SECOND,-300, U1.[DateTime]) 
                            AND DATEADD(SECOND, 300, U1.[DateTime])) ) X
WHERE X.CNT > 1
```

RESULT

```
IPAddress        UserName             DateTime
---------------- -------------------- -----------------------
198.168.1.101    User 1               2019-01-01 09:00:00.000
198.168.1.101    User 2               2019-01-01 09:00:05.000
198.168.1.101    User 3               2019-01-01 09:00:10.000
198.168.1.101    User 4               2019-01-01 09:00:15.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table has columns namely,

IP Address | UserName | DateTime |

and you need all users within first 300 seconds,

```
DECLARE @min_time DATETIME
SELECT @min_time = MIN([DateTime]) FROM UserAccess

SELECT * FROM UserAccess WHERE DATEDIFF(s, @min_time, [DateTime]) <300
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` might have good performance, with the right indexes:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t2
              where t2.ipaddress = t.ipaddress and
                    t2.datetime >= dateadd(second, -300, t1.datetime) and
                    t2.datetime < dateadd(second, 300, t1.datetime)
                    t2.username <> t.username
             );
```

I am guessing you want the user names to be different.

The index you want is on `(ipaddress, datetime, username)`.